# Defining instance variables in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, coding-style

As Objective-C has evolved (I use it exclusively with xcode/ios for iPhone/iPad development), there seems to be many different ways you can layout your class instance variables.  Is there a 'best practice' way that's become common consensus? (I realise Apple demo/example code is all over the place in terms of style)

In particular the idea of handling private variables.  Here are a number of ways I've seen to manage some instance variables for a class (I've left out the interface/implementation for brevity) - and I'm not even including the use of underscore named synthesized properties.

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *aString;
```

.m

```
@synthesize aString;

- (void)aMethod {
   aString = @"Access directly, but if I don't have custom getter/setters and am using ARC, do I care?";
   self.aString = @"Access through self";
}
```

Or this:

.h

```
@property (readonly) NSString *aString;
```

.m

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *aString;
...
@synthesize aString;
```

Or this:

.m

```
@interface aClass {
 NSString *aPrivateString;
}

- (void)aMethod {
  aPrivateString = @"Now I have to access directly, but is this atomic/nonatomic?";
}
```

I don't want this question to turn into a style argument, but it seems to me there should be a "if you're not doing something specific or complex or weird, use this method for defining your class variables" standard.

Comment: All access to ivars is non-atomic. When you make a property atomic and access it through the getter/setter, the synthesized methods add the atomicity. If you access an ivar directly, even if you set it as `atomic` in the property, the access will not be atomic. Global variables and statics are atomic by default (the compiler adds code, although you can disable this).

Comment: Apple's recommendations for ivar declaration and definition are pretty well outlined in [TOCPL](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-BAJHEIFE).

Comment: And just a note on nomenclature: a "class variable" is normally a variable associated with the class (single variable for each class) as opposed to instance variables that are associated with each instance (and can have different values for different instances).

Comment: Yeah thanks - I've updated the question.  I wanted to keep it general, but I guess global class variable definition is a separate question!

Comment: @JasonCoco "Global variables and statics are atomic by default" Can you post a reference to documentation on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd prefer use the following convention for public and private ivars/properties:

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *publicString;
```

.m

```
@implemention aClass 
{
  NSNumber *_privateNumber;
}
@synthesize publicString = _publicString;
```

This way everything starting with _ is an ivar (_publicString is the underlying ivar for the property, this prevents me from using publicString while I want to use self.publicString).

Comment: And in fact, it's Apple's recommendation that you leave it out.

Comment: "you dont need to declare" - You need to tell the compiler it exists through, right? Are you saying you'd prefer to define it via @property ... *_privateString; ... @synthesize?

Comment: @vikingosegundo/Josh If you read carefully you'll notice that I do not create an explicit ivar for the property. Only for the private ivar. _privateString and _publicString are two different ivar's and have nothing to do with each other. If was just a demonstration how I handle public properties and private ivars.

Comment: You're correct that I did misread, but private ivars should be declared at the start of the `@implementation` block rather than the `@interface`.

Comment: @Josh I have updated the answer to make it more obvious that the private and public ivars are separate.

Comment: or — as I prefer — at the class extension. I like to group it with the hidden properties.